# C# explicit cast superclass to derived class and get specific variables

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class, Tile.
I have another class, WebTile, inheriting the Tile-class.
The WebTile have a `private string html`, that Tile does not have.

```
 public abstract class Tile
{
    private string name;
    private string description;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
    }

    protected Tile(string name, string description)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

 public class WebTile : Tile
    {
        private string html;
        public string HTML
        {
            get { return html; }
        }
        public WebTile(string name, string description, string html) : base(name, description)
        {
            this.html = HTML;
        }
    }
```

I have a method that returns a list of Tiles `(List<Tile>)`

I loop through the list, and cast the Tiles of type WebTile to a WebTile.

And then i want to get the html-string. But it has become empty after the cast?! What am i missing?

```
foreach (Tile tile in xmlparser.GetTiles())
            {
                switch (tile.GetType().ToString())
                {
                    case "Dashboard.Tiles.WebTile":
                        WebTile _tile = tile as WebTile;
                        sb.Append("<div class=\"panel panel-default\">");
                        sb.Append("<div class=\"panel-heading\">" + _tile.Name + "</div>");
                        sb.Append("<div class=\"panel-body\">");
                        sb.Append(_tile.HTML); // <--- THIS IS EMPTY!!
                        sb.Append("</div>").Append("</div>");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
             }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's hard to help with so little information.

Comment: Really no more information is needed.. But ok, give me a sec

Comment: The constructor of `WebTile` sets `this.html` to its current value (which is null). Change it to `this.html = html;`. Also, if you want to check the type of `tile` use `if (tile is WebTile)` or use an `as` cast instead of switching on the type name.

Comment: @Lee Why is this null? It is added like `tileList.Add(new WebTile("name", "description", "some html here...");` The tilelist is then used above (`xmlparser.GetTiles()...`)

Comment: @Lee Okay, this solved the problem! Thanks!! I misunderstood you. And i saw that the thml should be = html; and not = HTML; THank you! :D

Comment: `HTML` is the property on `WebTile` which returns the current value of `this.html`. You are effectively calling `this.html = this.html` which is just setting it to its current value, which is `null` on construction. You need to set it to the local parameter `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class WebTile : Tile
    {
        private string html;
        public string HTML
        {
            get { return html; }
        }
        public WebTile(string name, string description, string html) : base(name, description)
        {
         //wronge
         // this.html = HTML;
         //correct
         this.html = html;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq's `OfType` method instead of switching off of the fully-qualified type name:

```
foreach (WebTile tile in xmlparser.GetTiles().OfType<WebTile>())
{
    sb.Append("<div class=\"panel panel-default\">");
    sb.Append("<div class=\"panel-heading\">" + tile.Name + "</div>");
    sb.Append("<div class=\"panel-body\">");
    sb.Append(tile.HTML); 
    sb.Append("</div>").Append("</div>");
 }
```

but your constructor is wrong - you were assinging the private field from the property, not the parameter that is passed in :

```
public WebTile(string name, string description, string html) : base(name, description)
{
    this.html = html;  // not HTML
}
```